# Moving user in Active Directory using PowerShell won't work

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to make a script that allows new users on the domain to be put into certain groups based on their tag e.g [DALT]. When I run the script it should work properly as it uses the correct OUs and target path but it seems to not work the way I expect it to. I use a credential saved on my D drive as the cred to have admin rights.

```
$deviceName = Hostname
$deviceName = $deviceName -replace '[^a-zA-Z]', ''
$defaultName = Hostname

# Import Cred for access to change Dir
$credential = Import-Clixml -Path 'D:\backgroundProcess\cred.xml'
$credential

# Directing users to different part of AD depending on deviceName

# Action House (Branch of Company)
if ($deviceName -eq 'DALT') {
    Move-ADObject -Identity "CN=$defaultName,CN=Computers,DC=internal,DC=ttlhidden,DC=co,DC=uk" -TargetPath "OU=Windows,OU=Laptop,OU=Computers,OU=DEKRA,DC=internal,DC=ttlhidden,DC=co,DC=uk"
    Write-Host "$defaultName added to Hidden group."

    gpupdate /force
}

else {
    Write-Host "Sorry, $deviceName is not a verified name, please contact Max for more information."
}

Remove-Item -Path 'cred.xml'
```

It always seems to render the else option even if my computer has DALT at the start.

Comment: What is a "tag", and why do you expect he device's hostname to contain it?

Comment: I refer to a tag as the shortening of a branch of a company ex we call action house DALT. I made it so it will get the DALT without the computers unique number so it can be put into the if statement to be placed in the right group in AD.

Comment: So all the devices belonging to employees at that branch are expected to have a hostname like `DALT-123`? Sounds like that might not be a safe assumption :)

Comment: Along the lines of that yeah

Comment: So what have you done to troubleshoot this? Does `(hostname) -replace '[^a-zA-Z]', ''` give you the expected string `DALT` when you run it in the console?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on my personal computer and worked fine (but on a new computer it doesn't have any networking permissions so it may be to do with my credential token but... before even asking for it, the script opens and closes within a second and within that second shows the else statement.

Comment: Right, but what is the hostname of the new computer? It sounds like you're relying on devices conforming to some company-specific naming convention _before the device has been configured by the company_ - that's unlikely to work...

Comment: Just tried it on my personal device. I need to find a way to allow me to login to the domain with my admin account.

Comment: It joined the company group but there are sub groups within the main one to specify its use and policies. This is where I am trying to move the computer to said group based on its tag.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a representable example of the computer names, where we can find what you call the _tag_. Also add some example OU's and sub OU's so it becomes clear what _tag_ moves to what OU. Also, your questions title is about moving **user** objects, but in your code you try to move **computer** objects, so which is it?